# How to upload file using service account and python

Tags: python, google-drive-api, service-accounts

I currently have a python code and already created a service account. I now need a way in order to upload file into a google drive folder shared to the service account.

Bonus points is finding first if a certain folder already exists, if not create the folder then upload the file over there.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Google Drive API documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference) and specially the [Quickstart guide with Python](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python). Also, read [this Stack Overflow guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write good questions. :D